# Refresh feature with Openlayers 3

Tags: dictionary, refresh, openlayers-3, layer

Is it possible to refresh a single feature of a vector layer with Openlayers 3? I don't want to refresh all the layer.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a single feature needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @JonatasWalker For instance, when manually drawing a feature, which style depends on information added to it on the server. Or possibly because the style needs to be changed for that specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ol vector source, you can try to remove the feature and add it again. The Add Feature function triggers a change event (for the whole source, but this shouldn't update already drawed features).

```
ol.source.Vector.prototype.addFeature = function(feature) {
  this.addFeatureInternal(feature);
  this.changed();
};
```

Comment: In my case, many users can work on the same map. If a user modifies a feature, the same feature has to be updated for the other users without updating all the layers.

Comment: Thats pretty difficult, because you have to trigger a notification to/from the server and push it or pull it the frontend. You can pull from the frontend every 5 seconds or somewhat, or use websocket to notify the frontend of an change.

Comment: I tried your method (remove the feature and add it again), but the feature disappears from the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the feature, you can update aspects of the feature like it's geometry or properties and that will be updated in the map.

`setGeomtry` and `setProperties` both fire events that make the map update:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html

As long as you have set things up so that you can find or keep a direct reference to the feature, you can use the methods detailed in http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html to update a feature